# From what scriptures are the stories of Jesus?

Tags: quran, prophet-isa

In the Koran there are stories told about Jesus. But is it known which source is used for those stories. In the christian bible the story of Jesus came from old papyrus rolls from around the years 200 AD. But how did they came in the Koran?

Comment: God revealed those stories to his Messenger (PBUH), and that's how they are in the Qur'an. very simple...

Comment: So they/he didn't use any scritpure??

Comment: No, Muslims believe the verses of Qur'an have been sent to Prophet Muhammad by the angel [Gabriel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel). That's how they are in the Qur'an and that is what Muslims believe.

Answer (score 3):

Allah (SWT) revealed those stories to his Messenger (PBUH) through Angel Gabriel (Jibreel).

Allah (SWT) says in Surat Hud:

> وَكُلًّا نَّقُصُّ عَلَيْكَ مِنْ أَنبَاءِ الرُّسُلِ مَا نُثَبِّتُ بِهِ
>   فُؤَادَكَ ۚ وَجَاءَكَ فِي هَـٰذِهِ الْحَقُّ وَمَوْعِظَةٌ وَذِكْرَىٰ
>   لِلْمُؤْمِنِينَ ﴿١٢٠
>
> And all that We relate to you (O Muhammad SAW) of the news of the
>   Messengers is in order that We may make strong and firm your heart
>   thereby. And in this (chapter of the Qur'an) has come to you the
>   truth, as well as an admonition and a reminder for the believers.
>   (120)

---

Reference:

- [www.tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#11:120)

Comment: I added it's Arabic Quranic verse to its English translation (with your permission). Jazak Allah Khaira